# Nearby places xamarin forms IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get all nearby places using the google places web service API. It works on Android (Simulator), but when i build and install the app on my iPhone, the httpRequest returns an "INVALID_REQUEST" response.

Here is my request:

```
placesResult = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new UriBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=AIzaSyAg-d-wLhMl65Fo_sfyj_U9tFOoW41UcDQ&location=" + position.Latitude + "," + position.Longitude + "&radius=500&type=restaurant").Uri.ToString());
```

I have set my API's restrictions to both none and IOS App and it still won't work.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Make sure your coordinates are in the correct format. They differ between iOS and Android

Comment: I am using the device's current location. I am not setting the location myself. I am using the GeoLactor plugin.

Comment: But does it provide coordinates in the format the google API wants?

Comment: Ahh, Yes. Thank you. On IOS the coordinates are provided with a comma instead of a period. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments. Android usually formats GPS coordinates differently from iOS. You should make sure to format your coordinates from iOS in a format that matches the format the API wants.

The correct format is something like:

```
-33.8670522,151.1957362
```